# Can SQL Profiler filter data columns only for one event?

Tags: sql-server, profiler

I am using SQL Profiler in MS SQL Server. I can filter data columns by clicking 'Column Filters'. But this filter applies to all events. I want to filter login only for 2 events. Like, audit login and logout only for specified login, but all other events for all logins. Is it possible to do that, and how if yes.
Thanks for your time!

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, this can't be done in the trace definition. Each filter defined executes sp_trace_setfilter filter which groups filters by column, but applies all the filters as a whole...

In the trace definition snippet below it ends up grouped like this:

(DatabaseId = 5 OR DatabaseID = 6) AND (DatabaseId <> 1 AND DatabaseID <> 0) AND (Login like User1 OR Login like User2)

```
-- Set the Filters
declare @intfilter int
declare @bigintfilter bigint

/******Filter by database ID include*****/
SET @intfilter = 5
exec sp_trace_setfilter @TraceID, 3, 0, 0, @intfilter  -- 3,0,0 = ColumnID, logical operator (and/or), comparison operator (0 = EQUAL, 1 = NOT EQUAL)

set @intfilter = 6
exec sp_trace_setfilter @TraceID, 3, 1, 0, @intfilter

/******Filter by database ID exclude*****/
SET @intfilter = 1
exec sp_trace_setfilter @TraceID, 3, 0, 1, @intfilter

set @intfilter = 0
exec sp_trace_setfilter @TraceID, 3, 0, 1, @intfilter

/******Filter by database Login LIKE*****/
exec sp_trace_setfilter @TraceID, 11, 0, 6, N'user1' -- 11,0,6 = ColumnID, logical operator (and/or), comparison operator (6 = LIKE)
exec sp_trace_setfilter @TraceID, 11, 1, 6, N'user2'
```

For real-time filtering you'd need to use something like the *Save to table* option and filter a query against the output there.